# Installing Windows 7 on bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp

I am trying to install windows 7 on bootcamp.Seems to go fine until it get to completing installation and re-boots.When it re-boots I get a black screen indefinately.

I have tried several times but it won't complete the installation.

Anyone have a clue.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have finally gotten it. I had to unplug my USB peripherals.